# 1 component calling 2 different APIs for integration

Tags: angular, api, integration, primeng

I have a component ts file in which it is reusable by 2 HTML - one for privileged users and one for non-privileged users. Both HTMLs calls/reuse the same component ts file. However, I have 2 APIs - one for privileged and one for non-privileged. How do I integrate both APIs when the HTMLs are reusing the same component file?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this using `if` statement and when condition is met call the respective API as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a service for the API calls (https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)

Then you can pass values to the component through @Input()
(https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

In the component you decide which call you make based on the input

Answer (score 0):

HTML and Typescript class forms one whole in Angular. One component, one html.

You can alter html structure with structural directives `*ngIf` or `ngSwitch` or your own directives at runtime.

Or you can create two different components for privileged and non-privileged users (move common functionality to service), altough maintainig one component can be simpler than two.